# How to get array into set of pairs using for loop and javascript map reduce functoins

Tags: javascript, arrays

[1,2,3,4,5,6] should be changed to set containing {1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{4,5},{5,6} using normal for loop and using javascript map and reduce functions convert array to set of pairs using different techniques Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you tried so far

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.,** and give it a try. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it thoroughly, [search thoroughly here](/help/searching), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Side note: There's no good reason to use `reduce` for this. People love to shoehorn array operations into `reduce` calls (because just about *any* array operation can be shoehorned into a `reduce` call), but there's usually no reason to. So if your assignment requires it, well, do it, but be aware that it's not necessarily the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not a simple for loop? Array functions are great but are often unnecessary.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
const result = []

for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i)
  result.push([arr[i-1], arr[i]])
  
 console.log(result)
```